# How can we export a common global opt out list from Sitecore EXM?

Tags: email, sitecore, sitecore-exm

I would like to see contacts in a common global opt out list. Is there a way to export the common global opt out list from  Sitecore EXM?

I checked in Dashboard from List Manager, but can not see any default common global opt out list.

Could you please advise me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ManagerRoot` class in EXM API has a `GlobalSubscription` property that contains an object of the `GlobalSubscription` type. This object can interact with the global opt-out list and using `GetAllExcludeCollections()` method you can retrieve a collection of all the global opt-out lists. Read more details [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/34/email-experience-manager/en/configuring-the-global-opt-out-list.html).